# How to assign a random number in Excel with conditions?

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

I want to assign a number between 1 to 6 in Column 2023 with the condition that each number should be equally assigned in 2023 and should not match any of the numbers assigned previously in 2020, 2021 and 2022. Excel experts are requested to extend their support, please.

[image: Excel Table]

Comment: What do you mean by `equally assigned`?

Comment: How can 6 numbers be equally assigned to 17 cells?

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following formula but this is not equally assigned.

```
=BYROW(A2:C6,
LAMBDA(rw,
CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(SEQUENCE(6),ISERROR(XMATCH(SEQUENCE(6),TOCOL(rw)))),RANDBETWEEN(1,3))
))
```

[image]

Comment: Why `TOCOL(rw)` and not just `rw`?

Comment: @JosWoolley You are correct. Actually I was building the formula part by part and forgot to remove when construct them into a single formula. Thanks for catching.

Comment: Yeah, thought so. I do the same myself quite often!